# Was this character's death symbolic in Bridge to Terabithia?

Tags: symbolism, bridge-to-terabithia, katherine-paterson

As a child, reading *Bridge to Terabithia*, I was horrified when

> Leslie died

As an older reader now, I wonder whether her death was necessary to the development of Jessie. Was her death for a purpose, or was it just the author giving a sence of mortality to her characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because *Bridge to Terabithia* was written in response to a genuine event. Author Katherine Paterson wrote the book after [her son's best friend was struck by lightning and killed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_to_Terabithia_(novel)).

The book is a reaction to mortality, but it's not symbolic. It's a way to try to process how unfair life can be, and how to cope with the aftermath of such an event.